# How can I make DIV appear when a certain class is on the page?

Tags: jquery, drupal, hide, show

I am using Drupal CMS. In Drupal there is a messages DIV that has a class of `.message`
When an error appears, the class `"error"` is added to the message DIV.

On my page, I have a DIV that has a class of `"instruction"`
I want this DIV to be hidden and only appear when the error class is visible.

Here is my code:

```
 (function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".instruction").hide;
    });

    if ($('.messages').hasClass('error')) {
    $('.instruction').show;
    }

})(jQuery);
```

However, it doesn't seem to work. How can I make it work? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a function call, you'll need to add `()` like this:

```
$.ready(function() {
    $(".instruction").hide();

    if ($(".messages").hasClass("error")) {
        $(".instruction").show();
    }

});
```

[Here's the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4tZnc/) (Remove the "error" from the HTML to see it work).